# Prestashop - js_def displays in output source code - $js_def does not display

Tags: javascript, global-variables, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In prestashop template variable `$js_def` should contain predefined global JavaScript variables with `addJsDef`.

However what happens is that instead of script with defintions of variables only string `js_def` is displayed in output source code.

PS: this is a share-your-knowledge-type Q&A

Answer (score 0):

Definitions displayed by using `$js_def` template variable are actually not in the `$js_def` variable itself. It only contains the string `js_def`.

So how is it displayed?

Those definitions are displayed by an automatic replace of `js_def` string in `<head>`.

## Possible cause and solution:

### Cause

Since it is done by replace on output source code - ***if an error happens while outputing - the replacement does NOT happen!***

This can even happen if there is an **undefined variable or index** used in some output template (.tpl) file , even `footer.tpl` error can still cause NOT replacing the `js_def` string in `<head>`.

### Solution

The solution is easy - check source code for any error and repair them. Once your output HTML source code will be error-free there is a 99.99% chance `js_def` will now be correctly replaced / displayed.